# Is it possible to know each time someone makes a post in a facebook group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I want my program to get notification each time someone makes a post to a facebook group. Is it possible to get this real time. I mean I want the event immediately after the post is made...?

If it is possible how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook provide real time push based notifications, using its [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/). But currently it do not support pages. So Currently you can not do it real time, 
you can make it real time by polling to facebook server for specific page with small pool time (may be few secs).

Comment: is it supported for groups...?